# Exclude '/category/' from menu links URLs in WordPress

Tags: php, hyperlink, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I work with wordpress site, where now category page is accessible from two types of links:

- http://SITENAME.com/category/CATEGORY-NAME/
- http://SITENAME.com/CATEGORY-NAME/

And from right-side menu the links shown as first type, which is wrong.
I need to setup side-menu links to looks like http://SITENAME.com/CATEGORY-NAME/ (without 'category' in every path). 
How it can be done? I haven't found such settings neither in admin panel nor in templates...

Comment: Is the 'right-side menu' a wordpress widget? Also, what solution did you use to exclude '/category' from urls?

Comment: I am not sure if it's widget or core wordpress functionality. I am quite well in PHP but still quite new to WordPress and this site was developed by another person, I only support it. I tried to find where this 'category' part of link is added, but have failed in this - looks like it's some tricky complex core thing without direct line of code in template.

Comment: is that a widget or something hard coded into the theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

The plugin requires no setup or modifying core wordpress files and will not break any links. It will also take care of redirecting your old category links to the new ones.

If you run a multilanguage site with WPML plugin, try this:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/